# Why does Firefox not load javascript refed from an html when served by my nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-chrome, firefox

I have a smallish webapp that runs in production in WebLogic.  I've been working on a front-end page that loads some css in the head and javascript at the end of the body.  This works fine in Firefox and Chrome (I have some javascript problems in IE, but that's not relevant to this question) when the files are served from WebLogic.

I'm also serving the files from a local nodejs server, simply as a development tool, so I don't have to build the whole app to test front-end changes.

When the files are served from the nodejs server, it still works fine in Chrome.

However, when the files are served from the nodejs server, the behavior in Firefox is odd.  It loads the HTML file and the CSS, but for some reason it just refuses to load the javascript files.  There are no errors on an attempt to load them, it just doesn't try.

I have both the nodejs server and weblogic running, and I've viewed the page results with Firebug.  I figure there must be something in the request or response headers that might give a clue to why this is happening.

Here are the request and response headers for the request for the HTML file to the WebLogic server:

```
Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Host    localhost:7001
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Content-Length  8645
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Sun, 16 Feb 2014 18:29:28 GMT
Last-Modified   Fri, 14 Feb 2014 23:46:34 GMT
X-Powered-By    Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
```

Here are the request and response headers for the request for the HTML file to the nodejs server:

```
    Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Host    localhost:8000
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Cache-Control   public, max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  8645
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Sun, 16 Feb 2014 06:45:56 GMT
Etag    "8645-1392421593000"
Last-Modified   Fri, 14 Feb 2014 23:46:33 GMT
X-Powered-By    Express
```

About the only thing that is curious is the "charset=UTF-8" in the Content-Type from nodejs. Why would that make it load the CSS, but not the javascript?

**Update:**
Here is the skeleton of the index.html page (I've elided most of the body content):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="DiagApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<title>... title ...</title>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/css/diag/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body >
<h1>... title ...</h1>
<tabset>
...
</tabset>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="/js/diag/diagapp.js"></script>
<script src="/js/diag/dataSourcesMod.js"></script>
<script src="/js/diag/queriesMod.js"></script>
<script src="/js/diag/handlersMod.js"></script>
<script src="/js/diag/workflowMappingsMod.js"></script>
<script src="/js/diag/constants.js"></script>
<script src="/js/diag/libs/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
<script src="/js/diag/libs/ng-table.src.js"></script>
<script src="/js/diag/libs/jquery.formatDateTime.js"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="pendingQueryDetail.htmlx">
...
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="completedQueryDetail.htmlx">
...
</script>
</body>
</html>
```